# Yii: model's Rules not validating with variables

Tags: php, yii

I'm using variables to populate the public function rules() inside a model, and the validation error inside CActiveForm (called in the view) is not triggering when the form field is left empty (even though it is labeled as required).

A) This is what shows as required, but doesn't validate (and I need it to validate)

```
array_push($required,'email');
array_push($rules,array(implode(',',$required), 'required'));
return $rules;
```

B) This is what shows as required, and does validate (exactly how it's supposed to work)

```
array_push($rules,array('email', 'required'));
return $rules;
```

How can I get example A validating like example B? (Both examples output the same.)

Update: Below is the whole function, for example A. (Doesn't validate.)

```
public function rules()
{

    $required = array();
    $rules = array();

    $model=self::getFields();

    foreach ($model as $field) {
       $field_rule = array();
       if ($field->REQUIRED=='1'){
          array_push($required,$field->VARNAME);
          //print_r($field->VARNAME); //outputs: email
       }
       if ($field->FIELD_TYPE=='VARCHAR'||$field->FIELD_TYPE=='TEXT') {
          $field_rule = array($field->VARNAME, 'length', 'max'=>$field->FIELD_SIZE, 'min' => $field->FIELD_SIZE_MIN);
          array_push($rules,$field_rule);   
        }
    }
    array_push($rules,array(implode(',',$required), 'required'));
    return $rules;
}

public static function getFields() {
    $form_id=Yii::app()->params['form-id'];
    $model=FormField::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('FORM_ID'=>$form_id), array('order'=>'POSITION ASC'));
    return $model;
}
```

Below is the rules function, for example B. (Does validate.)

```
public function rules()
{
    $required = array();
    $rules = array();

    array_push($rules,array('email', 'required'));

    $field_rule = array('email', 'length', 'max'=>'255', 'min'=>'0');
    array_push($rules,$field_rule);

    return $rules;
}
```

When I print_r($rules) before both returns in the functions above, I end up getting the same output array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => email [1] => length [max] => 255 [min] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => email [1] => required ) )
```

I wish it was a simple PHP error, but this leads me to believe it is a Yii issue.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your PHP code, not anything Yii-specific. Can you display the full code of the `rules` method in both cases?

Comment: I added the full code of rules for both cases.

Comment: In case A), did you `print_r($rules)` when displaying the form or when processing the form submission? Does the `email` field have a default value? Have you confirmed that your form submission sends an empty value for the `email` field (what happens if you `var_dump($model->attributes)` after assigning input to it)? What does the `getFields` function look like?

Comment: In case A) the `print_r($rules)` that I said are identical to case B) are happening on displaying the form. The form itself is just grabbing new information so all the values are blank. Yes after the form is submitted case A) will show empty attributes if I `var_dump($model->attributes` while the case B) attributes will be populated with what was in the form field. The `getFields` function returns all the form's fields so that the rules can be written, I've verified that the data is correct on page load (but I'll add it above so you can see it).

Comment: That's an interesting approach to generating rules, how are you generating the `params['form-id']` value (have you checked the DB query log to see what query is generated to load those fields, and that it matches what you expect)? What rules are printed in case A when you are processing the form submission (you might have to `exit` right after printing to see the result properly)? I'm sorry there are so many questions, but this doesn't look like a Yii-specific issue to me.

Comment: You were right, it ended up being the `params['form-id']`. I was loading it in the view and when I changed it to the controller it now works. Thanks so much for helping trouble shoot this with me.